# Limit goes to $\infty$, but wolfram alpha says its limit is $0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, wolfram-alpha

I have $(5/3)^n$, if I input this in wolframalpha.com I can see it goes to infinity as long as n increases, but if I go down in the wolframalpha webpage results it shows .... the limit is zero as long as n increases, am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: Of course not (That is, you are right!). Please put a screenshot of the Wolfram Alpha result, along with your input, so that we can decide what's the problem.

Comment: Don't see that [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(5%2F3)%5En+for+n+to+infinity). It helped if you posted the exact text you typed into WA.

Comment: I am trying to post a screenshot, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: @ChristianAndrews `as long as n increases` Read the screen more carefully. What's $0$ is the limit for $n \to -\infty\,$ which is of course correct.

Comment: oh man, sorry about that, You're right, I was wrong

Comment: Limits don't go anywhere. They either exist or don't, but they're not moving around to a samba beat.

Comment: To expand on what @zhw. said: The standard terminology goes something like, "as $x$ goes to $c$, the value $f(x)$ goes to $L$". That is, it's the dependent and independent variables ($x$ and $y$) that do the going, not the limit ($L$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've correctly said, the value of the limit approaches $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

I typed the limit into Wolfram|Alpha using these inputs:

> [limit n to infinity (5/3)^n](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20n%20to%20infinity%20(5%2F3)%5En)
>
> [lim_{n to infinity} (5/3)^n](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bn%20to%20infinity%7D%20(5%2F3)%5En)

And they both gave me the correct answers.

What I suspect you've done is this:

> [limit n to infinity 5/3^n](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n+to+infinity+5%2F3%5En)
>
> [lim_{n to infinity} 5/3^n](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bn%20to%20infinity%7D%205%2F3%5En)

Which is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5}{3^n}=0$ instead of the correct limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{5^n}{3^n}\right)=\infty$

**Edit: After you provided the screenshot:**

Look carefully at the input given by Wolfram Alpha on your screenshot.

$$\lim_{\color{red}{n \to -\infty}} \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n=0$$

The limit tends to $-\infty$ instead of $+\infty$.

**To avoid this problem in the future:** Type the limit explicitly rather than just typing $(\frac{5}{3})^n$ on Wolfram|Alpha as I have done on my top two examples.

Comment: Look closely:  $n \to -\infty$.

Comment: As zhw said in another comment, limits don't go anywhere. So I think you should not use that kind of phrasing as it misleads students.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are missing a pair of parentheses:  If you type

[`Limit[5/3^n, n -> Infinity]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B5%2F3%5En,%20n-%3EInfinity%5D)

You will get `0`, because the order of operations makes this equivalent to $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5}{3^n} = 0.$$  If you type

[`Limit[(5/3)^n, n -> Infinity]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B(5%2F3)%5En,%20n-%3EInfinity%5D)

you will get your intended result, which is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n = \infty.$$

Comment: Occam's razor agrees.

Answer (score 2):

You said down the page was a limit of 0. That's because they took $n -> -\infty$.  **Edit** OP shows the same thing circled on screen print.

Answer (score 0):

This sequence definitely approaches infinity as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: so, It could be a wolframalpha's mistake? because I trust in wolfram blind eye

Comment: My guess is that you forgot a parenthesis or input the limit incorrectly into Wolfram.

Comment: When I enter it into Wolfram Alpha, the limit comes back as infinity.